# Connecting methods Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, datastore, foursquare

I am currently using Oauth to allow a user to sign in through Foursquare, I then create a new session for this user. If the user is new to the system they are asked to sign in through Hunch, this can then generate a user profile based on information from both systems. I have them both signing in to each application separately, but how can I associate the user logged in with Foursquare to the one in Hunch. 
My idea for it was to somehow create a reference to the session id in the user model, or use the session ID as a parameter for the hunch sign in but I'm not sure if this would be the best idea. Is there any other way in which I can create the association?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be something like the following:

1. Send the user to foursquare to sign in
2. When the user returns, create a record in the datastore for them.
3. Send the user to Hunch to sign in, but include the ID of the record you created in step 2 in the continue URL.
4. When the user returns, use the ID embedded in the URL to add the user's Hunch info to their user record.

Comment: I tried to add the ID in the continue URL but it causes it to fail for example my redirect to Hunch is `http://hunch.com/authorize/v1/?app_id=111&next=http://localhost:8086/?access_token={{access_token}}/` The returned URL is `http://localhost:8086/?access_token=aaa?auth_token_key=aaa&user_id=aa&next=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8086%2F%3Faccess_token%qq%2F` but when parsing it cannot find the auth_token_key

Comment: @qwop It sounds like hunch isn't encoding URLs correctly. Have you tried passing it in another fashion - such as as part of the URL? Eg, http://foo.com/auth/user_id?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a parent association so that `SiteUser` is the parent of `FoursquareAuth` and `HunchAuth`.

When the user first logs in with Foursquare you create the `SiteUser` model and then create the `FoursquareAuth` model with `parent=just_created_user`.  Then when you send the user off to authenticate through hunch you include the user's id, or a session id in the callback parameter. When the callback happens you get the user's key and create `HunchAuth` with `parent=previously_created_user`.

The `SiteUser` model contains the combined information from both sources (name, location, last checkin, etc.). The `*Auth` models just contain whatever guaranteed unique identifiers are supplied by each provider (user_id, access_token, etc.).

This way, if you have the user object you can find either the Foursquare or the Hunch authentication data (using an ancestor filter), and you can find a user by loading any `*Auth` model and fetching its `parent()`.

(note: I call the model `SiteUser` to not confuse it with the `User` object available in App Engine)